# how to test that a click and pledge web form works correctly or not?

Tags: integration, web2lead, website-integration

I don't know how much you guys are familiar with click & pledge platforms 
I have created a webform on it and mapped with Salesforce fields but I can't test it because some payment information fields are required 
does anyone have a dummy test function to test this webform ?

Comment: What are you trying to test? Sounds like the form is off platform?

Comment: no it's a click and pledge platform 
I just want to check if the web form works well or not , but I can't find a dummy function to fill the payment fields and test the functionality of saving the content into Salesforce directly from the web form

Answer (score 1):

Rickey,

If you post your questions to our forum we will be able to reply to you much faster.  We do not receive alerts when questions are in this forum - I only noticed this by receiving a mention alert in Google.  Our forum is at:  https://forums.clickandpledge.com

As for your question.

If your transaction has posted please check a few things first:

-- Has C&P Data posted?
-- Is the transaction in the C&P Temporary Contact - if your mode is in semi-automatic, a contact that cannot be located based on the set conditions will be in the temporary Contact.  Nothing will be created until the Temp is handled.

You may wan

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to switch to test mode and run test card no.

See this cnp support article

http://help.clickandpledge.com/customer/portal/articles/1245601

> You change the status of a page to “Test” to run transactions with a “test” credit card number. This way you can run a transaction on a payment page without using a real credit card. “Test” status allows you can see exactly how you payment page preforms before you make it “Active.”

I believe this article may refer to the older cnp portal vs the new connect platform.  If so cnp support should be able to point you at the details for how to do this on connect.

Comment: this article points the old platform 
I'm working with a new 2017 version

Comment: The process should be similar.  If you can provide more details I might be able to help, they have a lot of different tools, faas, paas, connect, etc.

Comment: yes you are right 
I could do the test process . now I don't have any problem to run a test payment . 
the new problem is that by submitting a donation , no opportunity record is going to produce automatically associated to the contact(donor) and account(household) . 
can you help in this issue please?

Comment: Suggest reviewing your setup and reading their docs.  The record is probably sitting in temporary contacts.  Behavior depends on your settings and matching criteria.